# Overwritting the content of file on each std::ofstream call

Tags: c++, file, fstream

The following code

```
#include <fstream>
void print( std::ofstream &f, int a ) {
   f << a << '\n';
}

int main () {
   std::ofstream fout( "out.txt" );
   print( fout, 1 );
   print( fout, 2 );
   return 0;
}
```

produces an output like this

```
1
2
```

However I want to see only 2. In other words, I want to overwrite the content of the output file whenever I call the print.

The reason for that, is that I want to call an update function in intervals. As a result, each time the update function is called, the new stats should appear in the output file (not appending the current with previous one).

P.S: putting `fout.clear()` between the two print calls won't do the job.

Comment: Put `std::ofstream fout( "out.txt" );` inside print?

Comment: for this snippet yes it works. But as I said this is part of a biger code which I want to define things in headers and ...

Comment: You can reset the output position in the `ofstream` using the [`seekp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) method: put `fout.seekp(0)` between the `print()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [`std::ofstream::seekp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) to reset the output position between the `print()` calls

```
   std::ofstream fout( "out.txt" );
   print( fout, 1 );
   fout.seekp(0); // <<<<
   print( fout, 2 );
```

Note that `fout.clear()` just resets the error states of the stream.